# Custom claims in Laravel/lumen passport refresh token

Tags: laravel, oauth-2.0, lumen, laravel-passport

Need help sending custom data in refresh token? For example, I am trying to send session id within refresh token so that I don't have to depend on front end to send me session id when refreshing token.

Im looking at generateHttpResponse function inside League\OAuth2\Server\ResponseTypes\BearerTokenResponse and i guess i have to extend this class to edit following part?

```
if ($this->refreshToken instanceof RefreshTokenEntityInterface) {
            $refreshToken = $this->encrypt(
                json_encode(
                    [
                        'client_id'        => $this->accessToken->getClient()->getIdentifier(),
                        'refresh_token_id' => $this->refreshToken->getIdentifier(),
                        'access_token_id'  => $this->accessToken->getIdentifier(),
                        'scopes'           => $this->accessToken->getScopes(),
                        'user_id'          => $this->accessToken->getUserIdentifier(),
                        'expire_time'      => $this->refreshToken->getExpiryDateTime()->getTimestamp(),
                    ]
                )
            );
```

Comment: Why would you need session information when refreshing token? Normally the OAuth server should not have any knowledge of the user's session - these are completely different topics. In my opinion you should rethink why you want to put some more data inside of the refresh token.